# Highchart - xAxis weekly date can start given day?

Tags: charts, highcharts

I have a very basic 'line' weekly date graphic. I just need the date on x-axis to start the on given day of my first point. I have specified **pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 09, 25)** but it showing different week in a different month? How can I display week from given date in x-axis?

```
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            credits : {
              enabled : false
            },
            title: {
                text: false
            },
            xAxis: {  
                tickInterval:  7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                type: 'datetime',
                startOnTick: true,
                startOfWeek: 0,
                labels: {
                    format: '{value:%d/%m/%Y}',
                    rotation: -45,
                    y: 30,
                    align: 'center'
                } 
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'HH'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 09, 25),
                    pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
                }
            }, 
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Curva Tardía',
                    data: [18, 27, 36, 36, 10]
                }, {
                    name: 'Curva Temprana',
                    data: [9, 18, 27, 27, 90]
                },{
                    name: 'Curva Real',
                    data: [0, 36, 45, 89, 100] 
                }
            ]
        });
```

[image: gh]

Answer (score 1):

Easy to make mistake, in [`Date.UTC`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC), month is a 0 based index, which means initializing the function with 09 means it is setting month to October and not September.

By setting `Date.UTC(2018, 08, 25)` you will get the date you expect to be there:

```js
$('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'line'
            },
            credits : {
              enabled : false
            },
            title: {
                text: false
            },
            xAxis: {  
                tickInterval:  7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                type: 'datetime',
                startOnTick: true,
                startOfWeek: 0,
                labels: {
                    format: '{value:%d/%m/%Y}',
                    rotation: -45,
                    y: 30,
                    align: 'center'
                } 
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'HH'
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    pointStart: Date.UTC(2018, 08, 25),
                    pointInterval: 7 * 24 * 3600 * 1000
                }
            }, 
            series: [
                {
                    name: 'Curva Tardía',
                    data: [18, 27, 36, 36, 10]
                }, {
                    name: 'Curva Temprana',
                    data: [9, 18, 27, 27, 90]
                },{
                    name: 'Curva Real',
                    data: [0, 36, 45, 89, 100] 
                }
            ]
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Is there any way to plot x-axis based on week dates without adding up 7 days intervals?

Comment: Not really, the only two options you have are: as you have done it with an interval specifying the points, or to give each point a manual value (which you would still need to calculate using the above formula).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `startOfWeek` option:

```
xAxis: {
    startOfWeek: 4
}
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nL4vuz5f/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.startOfWeek

Comment: Thank you @ppotaczek badly needed this one.

Comment: Hi @Pradam, I am glad I could help. You can accept the answer.